# Points that lay on each path from A to B

Tags: algorithm, path, directed-graph

Assume that *G(V,E)* is a directed graph. If *A* and *B* are two distinct vertices of *G*, how can I find the vertices of *G*, that lay on each path from *A* to *B*?

I have an *O(VE)* algorithm (a point is appropriate if and only if after removing it there is no path from *A* to *B*), but I would be happy to have a faster one. Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** It seems that I wasn't clear enough: I would like to get the vertices that lie on **every** path between *A* and *B*.

Comment: If there are two separate paths from *A* to *B*, do you need both? what if they have a common part? And why isn't a BFS from *A* useful here? (it costs `O(V+E)`

Comment: It sounds like you want an algorithm to find all the vertices that lie on every path from A to B. Conceptually, find all the paths from A to B (perhaps excluding cycles?). Then find all the vertices that lie on every path. Is that it? That sounds like what you meant by "a point is appropriate if and only if after removing it there is no path from A to B".